# Guaranteeing sort order with an IAsyncCursor query?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using a collection with millions of records populated asynchronously, so there is no guarantee of order.

When querying the MongoDB FindAsync method will allow a filter to be added, but not a sort.

How do I ensure the order of records returned using IAsyncCursor?  I have an ascending index on a epoch date-stamp field in my collection, is that enough to guarantee the sort order?.

====================

An IAsyncCursor is returned by the FindAsync method. The records are returned in arbitrary batches which are processed using the following using using/while construct.

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
var filter = new BsonDocument();
var count = 0;
using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
{
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        var batch = cursor.Current;
        foreach (var document in batch)
        {
            // What order will these records be in? how do I guarantee order ascending by epochtimestamp?;
        }
    }
}
```

Will each async "batch" be sorted with respect to the entirety of the query? How do I guarantee records will be in the correct order?.

The ascending index on the epocdatestamp field would allow me to return a full sorted list(Takes a very long time because of the number of records).

Should I one time rewrite that full sorted list back to the DB in the order I need to guarantee? So that future IAsyncCursor querys will return records in order.

Do I need to do that? or is the ascending index enough?

Comment: You "guarantee" it by specifying the "sort" modifier to the query object before executing.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks for the prompt reply... I found that when using "Find" it is possible to add a sort, but not when using FindAsync.  Would you create an answer showing me where the sort is specified using the code snippet above?   That would help a lot.

Comment: It really is about ( well past ) by bedtime, and I have urchins ( well teenage ones ) to wake in the morning. But the documentation is quite clear for [FindOptions](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptions_2.htm) as an argument to [FindAsync](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindAsync__1.htm) where [Sort](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptions_2_Sort.htm) is also a property to [set](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_SortDefinition_1.htm).

Comment: @BlakesSeven, thank you, you are kind to respond when besieged by such monsters.  Hopefully I'll learn it well now :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A sort can be added to a `"FindOptions"` object and given to FindAsync as an argument.  In this case it's an ascending sort on a field called `epochtimestamp`.

Simple when you know how,

```
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
    var filter = new BsonDocument();
    var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending("epochdatestamp");
    var options = new FindOptions<BsonDocument>
                  {
                    Sort = sort
                  };

    var count = 0;
    using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter, options))
    {
        while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            var batch = cursor.Current;
            foreach (var document in batch)
            {
                // process document
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats fine, you just forgot to pass the FindOptions argument to the FindAsync method.

Comment: @Kickaha why is that count++ statement in the foreach loop. I didn't get that.

Comment: @Aravind I agree; it is intended to count the documents, and superfluous for the purposes of the example.

Comment: @Aravind ... This is a teaching moment so I'm not complaining you are wasting my time. It's a benign, and somewhat common practice to include a count statement in an example loop.  Cognitively it aids a beginner to understand the logic by adding a concrete example of functionality, in context. I'd appreciate if you'd not nitpick a little sugary detail like this, and maybe use some in your own examples from now on.  Have a good day.

Comment: @JakeStokes same thing, thanks. Please have a nice day.

Comment: @Kickaha Ahh.. I was not criticizing your answer. I gave a vote up to both your question and answer. My intention was only to understand if there was a reason for that count variable. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Kickaha I appreciate that you deem it a 'cognitive aid' and that your intentions are noble, however in my opinion beginners like myself benefit from seeing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), whereas adding sugar without explanation only serves to convolute and detract from the purpose of the answer. From the perspective of a newbie I would request that you don't include non-relevant 'benign common practice' in answers to specific questions. You speak of us 'wasting your time'; these answers are seen by hundreds of learners who all must now take the time to decipher extra detail.

Comment: @JakeStokes ... tldr; be polite, please don't waste my time.  Thank you.

Comment: @JakeStokes ... Yes, you value your opinion a lot.  That's not necessarily a bad thing, but pick your battles.  Quoting chapter and verse is petty... and a waste of your time.  Making an edit to a 3 year old question is the lowest thing on my priority list.  You have no idea the other things that need my attention. .... The purpose of the count statement:  The count was useful because of the huge size of the data sets.  Keeping track of how much incoming data was buffered for analysis in RAM before it was exhausted.   You will benefit most from implementing an actual project of your own.